# 401 Unauthorized Google cloud messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have created a GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) account for my Android Application.

I tested my app, and i am receiving notification successfully.

But when i use it after 3-4 days, it gives me `Unauthorized 401` error.  I create a news service and it works fine 
for some time, and it also starts giving me same error message after some days.

Kindly guide the reason behind this

Comment: @jankigadhiya I checked that question, its saying to create a new project. I want to know any other way of rectifying this error

Comment: that question has some other links to have you checked that??

Comment: Are you using a Client API key? If yes, try using a Server API key instead.